# Regex: Add html tag at the beginning of each line (which has no starting tag)

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

**I need to add** `<p class="mb-40px">` **at the beginning of each line that does not have this tag.**

**For example:**

```
<p class="mb-40px">moderniseringen av de omgivande flerfamiljshusen berodde helt på hans vilja.</p>

acţiunile de modernizare a blocurilor din jur depindeau în totalitate de voinţa lui.</p>

the modernization of the surrounding blocks of flats depended entirely on his will.</p>

la modernización de los bloques de pisos circundantes dependía enteramente de su voluntad.</p>
```

**Output:**

```
<p class="mb-40px">moderniseringen av de omgivande flerfamiljshusen berodde helt på hans vilja.</p>

<p class="mb-40px">acţiunile de modernizare a blocurilor din jur depindeau în totalitate de voinţa lui.</p>

<p class="mb-40px">the modernization of the surrounding blocks of flats depended entirely on his will.</p>

<p class="mb-40px">la modernización de los bloques de pisos circundantes dependía enteramente de su voluntad.</p>
```

**Apparently it's easy**

FIND: `^`

REPLACE BY: `<p class="mb-40px">`

But in this case, I will get double of the first tag on the first line:
`<p class="mb-40px"><p class="mb-40px">`

Comment: Why not use a macro? Put `<p class="mb-40px">` on every line, then replace two instances of it in a row `<p class="mb-40px"><p class="mb-40px">` with one `<p class="mb-40px">`.

Comment: I have to change 1200 files....cannot use macro for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?!<p class="mb-40px">|\h*\R|\z)`
- Replace with: `<p class="mb-40px">`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                       # beginning of line
(?!                     # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
    <p class="mb-40px">     # literally
  |                       # OR
    \h*                     # 0 or more horizontal spaces
    \R                      # any kind of linebreak
  |                       # OR
    \z                      # end of file
)                       # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: super answer, thanks @Toto

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?-s)^(?!<p class="mb-40px">)[\r\n]+`
- Replace with: `<p class="mb-40px">`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*

**OR**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(</p>)([\s\S]*?)^`
- Replace with: `\1\n<p class="mb-40px">`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*